# Why is my group by not grouping my values as expected?

Tags: sql

My project is a clothes factory and I have 3 tables.

1. Person   : A table that contains people's name
2. Category : Contains each category of clothes in the factory (sockets, shoes, etc.)
3. Quantity : The quantity of clothes for each person

```
SELECT  Name,
    sum(case when category = 'shoes' then quantity else 0 end) as 'Quantity_shoes',
    sum(case when category = 'shirts' then quantity else 0 end) as 'Quantity_shirts',
    sum(case when category = 'sockets' then quantity else 0 end) as 'Quantity_shirts',
    sum(case when category = 'hats' then quantity else 0 end) as 'Quantity_hats'
FROM person p
    join inventory i 
     on i.person_id = p.id
    join category c
      c.id = i.category_id
WHERE p = 'Paul'
GROUP BY name,
     category
```

And I'm trying to display something like this :

| Name | Quantity_shoes | Quantity_shirts | Quantity_sockets | Quantity_hats |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Paul | 8 | 25 | 38 | 0 |

But my result isn't that I expected... I got this :

| Name | Quantity_shoes | Quantity_shirts | Quantity_sockets | Quantity_hats |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Paul | 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Paul | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Paul | 0 | 25 | 0 | 0 |
| Paul | 0 | 0 | 38 | 0 |

It seems that I have one row for each category. So I tried to `groupbyquantity` but it doesn't sum my `quantity` and I have more rows.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please tag it with the database you are using.  Some database require the group by column in the select expr.  Remove the category from group by if you only want a row per name.  You don't tell us what the columns are in person, so I assume it's p.name in my answer below.

Comment: @AllanWind Thank you for editing my question. What was the problem with query ? And, my tables are very complex. This example is a simplification of the table. What information do you need?

Comment: Use triple quotes around code.  You showed you tried so happy to edit it for you.  I think it's very helpful if you share minimal create table, insert, and the query you have issues with.  Good job on showing us what you got and what you are looking for.  Give the query in my answer and whirl and let me know if if it works or how it fails.  Remember to edit question with the actual database you are using (sql is somewhat of a generic term).

Comment: Also, free tip, if you are designing the tables prefer using the same primary and foreign key names (person_id, category_id, etc).  This allows you to use natural joins which simplifies queries as you don't have to specify all the join conditions.

Comment: I used triple quotes around the code ! And I couldn't post it

Comment: Edit your question and see what I did... no magic as far as I know :-)

Comment: @AllanWind Yes, but that is exactly what I wrote ! You can see [here](https://pastebin.com/HA7JUxXf). When I edit the question and I change one letter in the query, I can't post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the above try this (I am guessing the column in person with the name is p.name in which case you may not even need the group by name):

```
SELECT
    Name,
    sum(case when category = 'shoes' then quantity else 0 end) as 'Quantity_shoes',
    sum(case when category = 'shirts' then quantity else 0 end) as 'Quantity_shirts',
    sum(case when category = 'sockets' then quantity else 0 end) as 'Quantity_shirts',
    sum(case when category = 'hats' then quantity else 0 end) as 'Quantity_hats'
FROM
    person p
    join inventory i on i.person_id = p.id
    join category c.id = i.category_id
WHERE
    p.name = 'Paul'
```